# Golang: Timing out SQS ReceiveMessage with WaitTimeSeconds vs with Context argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sqs

I can call SQS ReceiveMessage with

```golang
sqs.ReceiveMessageInput{
        QueueUrl: &mysqr.poolQUrl,
        MaxNumberOfMessages: 1,
        WaitTimeSeconds: 5,
    }
```

and context.TODO(), or with

```golang
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx2, cfn := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second * 5)
    defer cfn()
    rmo, err := svc.ReceiveMessage(ctx2, &rmi)
```

Let's assume there's nothing available to read in 5 seconds.

In the first case, it returns fine with no messages and no errors, in the second I get a `operation error SQS: ReceiveMessage, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , canceled, context deadline exceeded`.

It was nice of AWS to put context in the go SDK, but I'd rather use the WaitTimeSeconds argument, it just feels simpler. Is there a good principled reason to use the `context` approach instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It was nice of AWS to put context in the go SDK

You're conflating the `WaitTimeSeconds`, part of `ReceiveMessages` API, with the Timeout that you could *potentially* attach to a context.

WaitTimeSeconds is an important part of long polling SQS Queues.  Without it, empty queues would cause consumers to make api requests as quickly as possible, driving huge loads on AWS.  Exceeding the `WaitTimeSeconds` does not indicate errors - the request could legitimately take even many extra seconds on a degraded network.

Contexts can be used to abort SDK operations for reasons outside the realm of the SDK itself - `WithTimeout` is only one such use of contexts.  In a multithreaded application, you might also use a context to cancel multiple outstanding requests due to some fatal error elsewhere in the application.

So, firstly, thinking of `WaitTimeSeconds` as a timeout is incorrect.  Secondly, thinking of `Context` as a timeout is also incorrect - a context is much more than just controlling max runtime.

> but I'd rather use the WaitTimeSeconds argument, it just feels simpler.

They do different things.  `Context.WithTimeout` doesn't obviate `WaitTimeSeconds`.  Without `WaitTimeSeconds` (or a default setting on the queue), `ReceiveMessages` would return immediately and `Context.WithTimeout` would never get a chance to time anything out.

> Is there a good principled reason to use the context approach instead?

So no, certainly not.  There's a good reason to use contexts *in addition to* `WaitTimeSeconds` - even `Context.WithTimeout` might make sense with `ReceiveMessages` requests in some situations.  But even though they both take durations, there is no overlap in use case.    With or without a context, it's almost never correct to run `ReceiveMessages` with `WaitTimeSeconds` set to 0.